# Template changes not showing with Sulu

Tags: php, symfony, sulu

When I bootstrap a new project using the latest version and documentation, and then add some properties to the `homepage.xml` or render some text in the `homepage.html.twig` nothing changes.

In `homepage.xml` I added this

```
<property name="header" type="media_selection">
     <meta>
         <title lang="en">Header</title>
     </meta>
</property>
```

directly below the `article` property, and when I go to the admin page, the `header` doesn't show up.

Same thing with small changes to the twig file. When I dump the content var there, nothing shows up.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not familiar with Sulu, but I am guessing that this is a Symfony related issue and you are seeing a cached version. Try clearing the cache (see [How to Use the Console](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/usage.html)):

**Symfony Console**

For the production environment:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod
```

For the development environment:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=dev
```

**Sulu Console**

According to the comment by Daniel Rotter, the console for Sulu is slightly different, try:

```
php bin/adminconsole cache:clear --no-warmup --env=dev
php bin/websiteconsole cache:clear --no-warmup --env=dev
```

<strike>This is untested since I have no Sulu installation ready to try it.</strike> Confirmed by Daniel Rotteer (see comments),

Comment: Thanks! I can now see the header on the admin page. Twig however is still acting weird, saying dump is an unknown function.

Comment: Difficult to say what the problem is, without knowing the template file. Maybe opening a new question with this would be a good idea.

Comment: Yeah really difficult to explain as well. I'll take another look, I think it's something Symfony related or some config parameters not set correctly. Thanks for your answer though! Really helped me out with my first problem!

Comment: Hey Sulu creator here :-) The thing is that we have two different kernels, so the console commands are slightly different. We have `bin/adminconsole` and `bin/websiteconsole`, so you probably have to execute both of them.

Comment: @DanielRotter: Thanks, I updated my answer to what I think is right. Can you confirm that?

Comment: This one here is now the suggested command for development I think: `SYMFONY_ENV=dev bin/console server:run`

Answer (score 2):

So I found the solution. I ran the command `rm -rf var/cache` from the project directory and then the Twig changes were rendered on the page.
So  Icarus's answer was right, but for some reason the commands he said, didn't work for both my problems.

Comment: I did not check whether the symfony console is part of the Sulu CMS. Maybe the creators of Sulu left it out, though this does not make sense to me. I am glad that I have helped one way or another :)